# Unable to create a azure b2c tenant with bicep

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-bicep

I'm trying to create a azure B2c tenant with bicep. When I do it in the portal everything is ok. With terraform also everything is ok. But with bicep I get this

> New-AzSubscriptionDeployment : 5:41:21 PM - The deployment 'xpto-devTEST' failed with error(s). Showing 2 out of 2 error(s).
> Status Message: The response for resource had empty or invalid content. (Code:ResourceDeploymentFailure)
> Status Message: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see
>
> - {
>   "error": {
>   "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
>   "message": "The response for resource had empty or invalid content."
>   }
>   } (Code:InternalServerError)
>   CorrelationId: c0a20039-0a78-44c3-94fb-998c53c661a4
>   At line:1 char:1
>
> - New-AzSubscriptionDeployment -Name xpto-devTEST -Template ...
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzDeployment], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureSubscriptionDeploymentCmdlet
>   ```

My main bicep have this

```
@description('the name of the environment. this must be dev, test, or prod.')
@allowed([
  'dev'
  'test'
  'prod'
])
param environmentname string = 'dev'

@description('the location of the resource')
param location string = 'northeurope'
@description('Name of the resource group')
param resourceGroupName string = 'xpto-${environmentname}'

targetScope = 'subscription'

resource rg 'microsoft.resources/resourcegroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: resourceGroupName
  location:location
}

module azureb2c 'modules/azureB2C.bicep' = {
  name: 'xptoTenant-${environmentname}'
  scope: rg
}
```

My module have this

```
@description('The name of the environment. This must be dev, test, or prod.')
@allowed([
  'dev'
  'test'
  'prod'
])
param environmentName string = 'dev'

@description('The location of the resource')
param location string = 'Europe'

resource b2c 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2019-01-01-preview' ={
  name: 'xpto${environmentName}Tenant.onmicrosoft.com'
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: 'PremiumP1'
  }
  properties:{
    createTenantProperties:{
      displayName: 'xpto-${environmentName}-tenant'
      countryCode: 'PT'
    
    }
  }
}
```

The Command that I'm running is this

```
New-AzSubscriptionDeployment -Name xpto-devTEST -TemplateFile main.bicep -TemplateParameterFile .\main.parameters-dev.json -DeploymentDebugLogLevel All
```

Can Anyone help me?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

***It is not possible to create from any IAC tools . As `Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2019-01-01-preview` Rest API hasn't been added to the [`IAC modules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.aad/domainservices?tabs=bicep).***

**As an alternative you can use [`Az CLI`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) along with [`Rest API's`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/activedirectory/b2c-tenants) with the below script :**

```
az login

SUBS=`az account show --query "id" -o tsv` \
RG=b2cdemotest \
DOMAIN=b2cdemo1ansuman \
LOCATION=westeurope

az group create --name $RG --location $LOCATION


# deploy

az rest --method put --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBS/resourceGroups/$RG/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/$DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=2019-01-01-preview --body @b2c.json --verbose


# get

az account tenant list

az rest --method get --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBS/resourceGroups/$RG/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/$DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=2019-01-01-preview | jq


# delete

az rest --method delete --url https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$SUBS/resourceGroups/$RG/providers/Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories/$DOMAIN.onmicrosoft.com?api-version=2019-01-01-preview --verbose

> verify if B2C tenant was removed then remove the Resource Group

az group delete --name $RG
```

`b2c.json file`

```
{
    "location":"europe",
    "sku": {
        "name":"Standard",
        "tier":"A0"
    },
    "properties": {
        "createTenantProperties": {
            "displayName":"b2c-demo-ansuman",
            "countryCode":"PL"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thks I will try that! and I will give you feedback about it

Comment: This has nothing to do with any of that. Issue is with a naming, answer above is correct. This shall be removed as answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
resource b2cDirectory 'Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory/b2cDirectories@2021-04-01' = {
  #disable-next-line no-hardcoded-location
  location: 'Australia'
  name: '<your-name>.onmicrosoft.com'
  sku: {
    name: 'PremiumP2'
    tier: 'A0'
  }
  properties: {
    createTenantProperties: {
      countryCode: 'AU'
      displayName: '<Your description>'
    }
  }
  tags: {
    Department: 'Dev'
  }
}
```

Works! Probably name is important and you need to name your resource with a valid DNS name.

Comment: I will try this, after August. I will let you know then.